# Newtonsoft.Json serialize double formated as string

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have the following situation:

- One `BankAccount` object with an `DoubleAmount` property that is a double.
- I do some operations in order to calculate the `DoubleAmount` field (i.e. aggregations, etc).
- When I return this as a JSON to my front end I would like to get it already well formated. For example: `100.000` formated as `100k`.

To achieve this what I am currently doing is the following class:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    public string Amount { get; set; } // This is serialized

    // This property is used to do the calculation
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double DoubleAmount { get; set; }

    public void FormatNumbers() {
        // This method is called after I finish doing the calculations
        // with my object and what it basically does is read DoubleAmount,
        // format it and put the value on the Amount string.
    }
}
```

The thing is this class doesn't feel right. I shouldn't have to call my `FormatNumbers`... I can somehow update my `Amount` everytime I update my `DoubleAmount`, but still it feels weird.

Anyway, do you guys know of any other better way of achieving this? 
Feel free to suggest anything. Thanks!

Comment: So, you want to *ignore* the actual data and serialize something which wont easily parse back to a number?

Comment: I would create a `FormattedAmount` property whose `get` method formats `DoubleAmount` on-the-fly and is automatically run when the object is serialized.

Comment: Take a look at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverterAttribute. You can implement a converter which will format a property however you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a method which you **have** to **remember** to use, because this violates **C** in [**ACID**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) set of rules. C stands for "consistency". If you have a formatting method, this is possible:

```
account.DoubleAmount = 100000;
account.FormatNumbers();
Console.Write(account.Amount); // "100k" = ok
account.DoubleAmount = 0;
Console.Write(account.Amount); // "100k" = inconsistent = very bad
```

Use custom getter instead:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double DoubleAmount { get; set; }

    public string FormattedAmount
    {
        get
        {
            return (this.DoubleAmount / 1000).ToString() + "k"; // example
        }
    }
}
```

If you use C# 6.0, this code becomes shorter:

```
public class BankAccount
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    public double DoubleAmount { get; set; }
    public string FormattedAmount => $"{this.DoubleAmount / 1000}k";
}
```

Still, you should only serialise (store offline) raw, unformatted values (double), and format (to custom string) only on the fly, at runtime, just when you need to display them.

Comment: duh! I knew it would be something simple! I was just imagining if it was something with `Newtonsoft.Json`. I will check @glenebob suggestion on `JsonConverterAttribute`, but will accept this answer as it solves for me! Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I edited the SOLID, but now I do not understand ACID which I associate with databases.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain the "C" :)

Comment: ... and edited to show how short this can get in C# 6.0!

Answer (score 5):

Example usage of JsonConverter. Note that the example converter here just does a default double/string conversion. You'll need to implement the actual conversion you want. This approach works for serialization and deserialization, assuming you implement the conversions correctly.

```
public class BankAccount
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleJsonConverter))]
    public double DoubleAmount { get; set; }
}

public class DoubleJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(double));
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return double.Parse((string)reader.Value);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue($"{value}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @glenebob! The `getter` solution for such a simple one-way converter I need works just fine, but I will keep in mind the existence of this for later uses!

Comment: *Nothing* is a subclass of double, it's a primitive and a struct. `objectType==typeof(double)` is more appropriate.